# How to extract attribute values from xml?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, celementtree

If I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dat>
<concept1 id="001" code="246545002"/>
<concept1 id="002" code="938374749"/>
</dat>
```

I can locate all `concept1` branches by doing

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.ElementTree(file='negation.xmi')

root = tree.getroot()

for elem in tree.iterfind('concept1'):
        print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

i.e.

```
concept1 {'id': '001', 'code': '246545002'}
concept2 {'id': '002', 'code': '938374749'}
```

How do I access the attribute values? i.e. see if `code` for `concept1` is equal to `code` for `concept2`?

Comment: just `elem.attrib['code']`. It's a dictionary.

Comment: Dictionary indexing. You can do `concept1['code'] == concept2['code']` to check if `code` is the same for `concept1` and `concept2`.